# opening a new tab in windows 10 edge doesn't allow setting to home page

Tags: microsoft-edge

How can I set Windows 10 Edge to go to a particular page, like google when i open a new tab, ie google.  This can be done in IE but not Edge?

I have tried the settings but it limits to 3 options, blank, top sites and top sites and recommended sites. I need a 4th option, custom or home.

Comment: The answer, as you discovered, is that this cannot be done in Edge. What I do now is set the homepage to Google, or whatever you want, and Alt+Home as usual. If you really need it I suggest a different browser.

Answer (score 2):

The issue of specifying a URL when opening a new tab in the Edge browser is currently being addressed by Microsoft. There is a "work-around" solution available. Follow these steps:

1. In the Edge browser, navigate to Settings > View Advanced Settings (located at the bottom of the Settings pane)
2. Turn on **Show the home button**
3. Enter the URL you wish the Home button to navigate to

Now simply select the home button after you have opened a new tab to navigate to the desired site.

Comment: Lol, "simply select Home button" is not an option for 90% of users, if you can't let me to choose which page to load in new tab this is game over MS. I gave Edge a chance, but options to configure browser are scarce, not nearly enough for 2016.

Answer (score 0):

**work-around** - almost as fast as it used to be.

1. Turn on the Favorites Bar in Edge
   (how to do that? Click/tap on the More Actions button at the top right corner, and click/tap on Settings. Under Favorites Bar, turn On (default) or Off.)
2. Navigate to the page of your choice.
3. Bookmark this page as a favorite by clicking the star in the address bar.
4. When saving the page as a bookmark/favorite, choose Create In -> Favorites Bar.

To open a new tab, right click the bookmark of your choice in the favorites bar and choose Open In New Tab.